# Replacement RDRAM chips for my Sony PS2

Tags: repair, sony-playstation

Oh yeah, just my luck, while I have my PS2 open to replace the clock battery one the magnet I use to hold the screws sticks to the RF shielding, comes off, and lands on the memory chips, cracking one of them.

The console is an SCPH-39001, with the ram marked "Z05755;TAIWAN 2309AD;59RM716agb-8". The Rambus logo is also on the chip where it sits, mocking me and savoring my state of suffering.

I do not plan on cannibalising another PS2, and I'd like the replacement to be as cheap as possible.

Those Rambus pc memory modules perhaps? Unfortunately RDRAM modules have heatsinks so I can't look at the chips and PCB through listing photos.

Comment: did you check whether it works? I don't know the PS2 memory chips but it may be that only the outer case is cracked.

Comment: I got a Samsung MR16R0828BN1-CK8. 128MiB of PC-800 RDRAM, 8 chips. It's close, REALLY close! Down to the layout of the pins on the BGA close! Unfortunately the physical dimensions of the BGA layout is smaller then my SCPH-39001. The pads are smaller and there closer together.

Comment: I'm sure with ENOUGH searching one can get the right chips. The pin functions and layout and stuff seems standardized. The main issue seems to be the BGA dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a very unfortunate situation, and unfortunately, the easiest solution to it would be to cannibalize another PS2. Using an RDRAM stick as a donor might work, but it must be picked precisely.

SCPH-39001 has two RDRAM chips, 16 MB each. As a replacement, you need to pick PC800 (400 MHz) memory chips. It might be best to replace both chips at the same time.

While, probably possible, it would be extremely hard to find a suitable replacement chip alone. It might be easier and cheaper to find a PS2 in a non working condition, the motherboard may even be damaged, but it doesn't matter as long as the RAM chips are intact. It doesn't have to be the exact same model, anything up to SCPH-77XXX would work.